# Appending a table to another table in the DOM. Targeting with no class or id available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently attempting to append a specific , via jquery, to another table. Here's the HTML, and the two elements involved in the move.

```
<div id="content_area">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td> <-- TD needing to move -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> <-- Needs to move-->
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="190" valign="top">
                <table width="100%"></table>
                <-- Move Above TD Here -->
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Although I'm hardly experienced with jquery/javascript, I have used the following method in the past to append a div to another div.

```
$(".target").appendTo($(".destination"));
```

This method I have used in the past required that the elements have some sort of unique identification. Since this is not possible with the current site I am developing (The software has locked down the HTML), how can I target these two tables in order to make the append?

You can view the issue at the following page:
http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/Pro-Audio-Equipment-s/1824.htm

It's pretty obvious to see on that page what I'm trying to accomplish with the move. Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you always have the table that you want to move before the table you want to move to, or are there different combinations?

Comment: No, the position of the tables is static for all category pages. That's why I'm still hopeful that they can be targeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Find the td we want to move.
var tdToMove = $('#divWaitModal + table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) td');

//Find the td we want to insert into after.
var tdToInsertAfter = $('#divWaitModal + table + table tr:first-child td:first-child');

//Detach the td to move.
tdToMove.detach();

//Insert it at the proper place.
tdToInsertAfter.after(tdToMove);
```

Comment: Rusmus, I attempted this bit of code, but it seems to be targeting a lot more tables than just the two we're after. How does the (tableToMove) come into play here?

Comment: Well, `$('table');` selects all the tables on the page, and `$('table').first()` takes the first one of the bunch. This table is then appended to any table that is inside another table, which I can see from your link, that you don't want. I'll take a look again and update my answer.

Comment: @AlexRitter I've updated my answer and added a jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks @rusmus. Your answer does indeed solve what my original question asked. Thanks for that. I have just noticed that the #content_area div is present on all pages on my site. As such, a page that does not contain categories is still moving tables around. Bummer. I don't know if this helps you or not, but I found the following css selector that correctly targets the exact TD I want to move, and just on category pages. #divWaitModal + table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) td

Comment: Do you want to move the table or just the td?

Comment: I just realized that I only want to move the TD. Sorry for the miscommunication. I'll update my question.

Comment: Upon further detailed inspection, I have noticed that in order to accomplish what I want to, I will have to move a td element to an area outside any table. I can only imagine how messed up this could look on certain browsers. However, the above did answer my original question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use child number of the node and target trough that :

```
$('body table:first-child').appendTo( $('table:eq(1) td:eq(0)') );
```

In words it takes the first table and it's appending it to second table > first cell. You can use :eq( number ) where number starts from 0, or first-child selector in some cases ..

Comment: I like where this idea is going. Targeting the first table from the body element is selecting the navigation menu table :). How would I edit this code to target the first table inside the #content_area div?

Comment: It shoud be : $('#content_area table:eq(0)')

Comment: K. I just tried  $('#content_area table:eq(0)').appendTo( $('table:eq(1) td:eq(0)') ); , but it seems to still be targeting the main navigation menu. You can check this out at: http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/Pro-Audio-Equipment-s/1824.htm

Comment: I've created a jSFIDDLE demo containing the example code .. its working as expected here : http://jsfiddle.net/8L9B8/ I didn't get into details in your page as it's quite complex .. probably there are more tables or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Goran. Using the following code snippit, I have successfully targeting the table I want to move. However, the code to append it apparently is not working, as I can not find the table on the page. $('#content_area table:eq(0)').appendTo( $('#content_area table:eq(1) td:eq(0)') );

Comment: Try to debug it step by step, try the second selector in console and see if it's capturing anything : console.log( $('#content_area table:eq(1) td:eq(0)') );

Answer (score 0):

This CSS might accomplish what you're after:

```
#content_area {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content_area table {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

If you want to target the elements, you can use the `#content_area` as a selector:

```
var $tables = $('#content_area>table');
var $table1 = $(tables[0]);
var $table2 = $(tables[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the css attempt james. If it was possible, I'd love to just use css. I'm interested in how you targeted the two tables, could you give a code snippit example of how you would use this targeting example to append the table?

Comment: Looks like you moved the code on the page around since I posted this... I'd want to hack around with it a bit before posting an updated snippet.